# Are two proofs better than one?

Tags: soft-question, formal-proofs

I have proved a simple conjecture two ways, for an essay I need to do for my highschool maths. How do I justify in my essay why I have included two proofs instead of one. Is there any good reason, to show that more than one proof is beneficial?

Comment: Absent context, there's really nothing to say here.  If the claim is more or less obvious, and the proofs simple and direct, then  one should suffice.  If the claim is more complex, and the proofs more subtle then there could well be an advantage in presenting two different arguments.

Comment: The vast majority of the time one proof is sufficient.  If the theorem is very interesting and the proofs are substantially different, revealing different insights, then it might be worth it to include both.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes that happens. For instance, it may be the the case that one proof is a smart but hard to find proof, whereas the other one, although longer and not particulary bright, is the natural approach to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you assume the pedagogical notion that the function of a proof is to convince the general reader of correctness of the result; then there being multiple proofs in general is good as it is more convincing.

On the other hand, the function of your writing should be considerate towards the reader's needs. How will the 2 proofs benefit them?

Perhaps if you *must* mention both proofs, then either confine one to an appendix or mention one in the minutest detail.